# Python3: Import class problems

Tags: python, class, import, directory

Suppose we have a tree like this:

```
└── my_project
    ├── A.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── my_apps
        ├── app_framework.py
        ├── app1.py
        ├── app2.py
        ├── __init__.py
```

Inside the folder `my_apps`, there is a general class defined in `app_framework.py`. The rest of the files all defines their own child class based on it.

The files would look like:

`app_framework.py`:

```
Class App():
    ...
```

`app1.py`:

```
from app_framework import App
Class MyApp1(APP):
    ...
    ...
```

`app2.py`:

```
from app_framework import App
Class MyApp2(APP):
    ...
    ...
```

So, in my project folder, I want to use

```
from my_apps import MyApp1, MyApp2
```

But I got two errors:

1. First is `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named app_framework`. I partially fix it by changing `from app_framework import App` to `from .app_framework import App`
2. `ImportError: cannot import name 'MyApp1' from 'my_apps'`

I can use `from my_apps.app1 import MyApp1, MyApp2`, but I would prefer `from my_apps import MyApp1, MyApp2`, which looks more concise. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `__init__.py` file in `my_apps` and import the required classes into that file:

```
# my_project/my_apps/__init__.py
from .app1 import MyApp1
from .app2 import MyApp2
```

Then in your `A.py` you can do:

```
from .my_apps import MyApp1, MyApp2
```

Comment: How to write something to load everythibg without specifying each of them？

Comment: How to do from . import * in that __init__.py file？

Comment: `from x import *` uses the `__init__.py` file to decide what to import, you now need to create that `__init__.py` so that you can do `from my_apps import *`. There's no "magical" way to import everything from everywhere. See the link I posted above.